# Range Data annotations Attribute isn't working with .net 6.0 webview C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a database in vscode and with my model class everything works such as Required Atrribute or maxlength but for the int variables withing the model class I want the value to between two values

so I used Range(40,160) for example

here is the model class called Profile

```
public class Profile
{
    [Key]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Range(18,80)]
    public int Age { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Range(40,160)]
    public int MonthlyHours { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Study { get; set; }  
    public List<Ability> Abilities{get; set;}

   
}
```

And once I create migrations with this command:

dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigrations

I get the following migrations class

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

#nullable disable

namespace Users.Migrations
{
    public partial class InitialMigrations : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "profiles",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(30)", maxLength: 30, nullable: false),
                    Age = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    MonthlyHours = table.Column<int>(type: "int" ,nullable: false),
                    Study = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_profiles", x => x.Name);
                });
```

and reading this class there's no specification for the range I typed in the model class unlike other attributes and after I created the database with this command

dotnet ef database update

I was able to add rows with values outside the range I made in model class

I have seen similar questions but none of them helped solving my problem

all the versions of packages in .csproj file are 6.0.10

any idea what's the problem ?

Comment: How would you expect the database to enforce that requirement

Comment: so the range attribute will only take effect with the http requests ?

Comment: It can do whatever you want it to. It just has to be coded

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the way you use it. `[Range(40,160)]` It is only used as a validation of the data model, not to limit your input in the database.
You can refer to Microsoft's official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: when does the validation happen after the client post the data ? or the server will refuse the input and won't be added to the database? or I need to check the value manually from the controller ?really sorry I'm still new to this and confused a little

Comment: No manual checking is required, these limits are checked when the object is created and an error message is returned to the frontend. Validation attributes let you specify the error message to be displayed for invalid input.

Comment: You can try it yourself. Calm down and study the official documentation.The introduction inside is very helpful for you to understand it.